# How can I downgrade from IE8 to IE7?

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, flexbuilder

How can I downgrade from IE8 to IE7 on Vista?

I want to downgrade because my Flex Builder does not correctly close the browser when debugging Flex Applications.  I'm sure this may be fixed in some future release of Flex Builder or IE8, but for now, I'd like to downgrade in order to debug more effeciently.

Comment: Clicking on the compatibility button in the top right corner enables the IE7 engine in IE8.

Comment: This probably won't fix a problem with a program misbehaving in using IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another option, just click the "Fix it" button on this page:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700/en-us

Comment: I couldn't find a "Fix it" button on this page, but following the steps in this KB article appeared to work for me. I was able to uninstall IE8 and revert to to IE7.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove updates in the "Uninstall program" dialog. In the task pane on the left is a link to installed updates where you can uninstall "Windows Internet Explorer 8".

Comment: This helped me realize that the IE8 had installed as part of a windows vista update.  I went to Control Panel, Uninstall a Program.   Then clicked on the View installed updates (instead of the normal programs list).  I was able to find and remove Internet Explorer 8, but unfortunately, IE7 wouldn't run afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting a standalone IE7 as an option. See if you can use your flex builder with this.

http://tredosoft.com/IE7_standalone

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

Comment: This didn't work for me.  After installing IE7_standalone, it gave me some errors about missing DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you uninstall it, in either Vista or XP.  Go to Start > Run, and then type in (carefully), the following line:

%windir%\ie8\spuninst\spuninst.exe

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question specifically mentions downgrading to IE7, but I just thought I'd mention that after successfully removing IE8 by following the instructions mentioned in PQW's link (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700/en-us) on my Windows Server 2003 machine I was left with a fully working version of IE6 and therefore didn't need to reinstall IE7.